# Mailto Script in php

Tags: php, scripting, for-loop, mailto

I am new to Php and I want to know how `mailto` script works in php? Can anyone please provide a script for that?

Answer (score 6):

It's actually very simple: Just use php's "mail" function. See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

It's as easy as typing

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: some@address.com");
```

This returns a boolean so you can check to see if it was sent successfully (it will be, unless your server's mail system is misconfigured) by doing something like:

```
$success = mail([...]);
if ($success)
    echo "your message was sent successfully";
else
    echo "your message did not send for some reason :(";
```

or even just

```
if (mail([...]))
    echo "success";
else
    echo "failure";
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP's built-in mail command is useful and works for most cases - simple & sparse. If you need more features, trying use a mail script like [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/).

Answer (score 3):

See [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

[Article](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How_to_Send_Email_from_a_PHP_Script.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Of course the easiest way to do it is using PHP's mail() command but it is not particularly efficient. The [PEAR Mail Package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) is a good option or you can use a PHP class. (You can find loads on [PHP Classes](http://phpclasses.org).)

Answer (score 1):

To save a lot of heartache, use something like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org).